# Reachability "No such module" error - How to add .m file to project

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm having issues getting [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) to work with my project. I have followed the instructions given but the call to import Reachability just throws the error "No such module Reachability". I don't think this is anything to do with the module, I think it my newbie lack of skills; could someone please tell me how to properly add/link a .m file to a project.
Thanks in advance!
Gareth

[image: Screenshot of project/error]

Comment: You don't need to `import Reachability`. You had add this to Bridging-Header and it worked.

Comment: Hi Codus - Thanks for the input. I did add a Bridging-Header but it didn't seem to work. It was probably down to me though as my knowledge isn't quite there yet! :-)

Comment: Did you import it in Bridging Header? Did you set bridging Header in build setting?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply Codus - I think so?! It was linked to in the build settings. I'm going to give Ashley Mills version of Reachability a go as it's newer but it's bugging me why the other didn't work. I guess that's part of the learning curve though eh?!

Comment: Open .xcworkspace not .xcodeproj (worked for me)

Answer (score 1):

I can see you have added .h and .m file, no need of that. We have Reachability Swift version available just used that using POD or direct add file in your project.

https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

And look for example in same link to know how to use it.

Comment: Tried this version of Reachability (other one much older!) - works perfectly! Thanks Joe.

Answer (score 0):

I see why you're getting this error , here is an easy way to solve it ,
go to your project setting where you find

Info - > bUILDING SETTINGS - > Package Dependencies [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLBtL.png)

now go to Package dependencies , and delete Reachability or any other.
Download the package again and all will be fine

Comment: It is: Project > Targets: your target > Package Dependencies